How can I look for a keyword in a jcr:contains query?
When I try a JCR query like the following:
//en/US/EAP//element(*,EAP:Article)[(@hippo:availability='live') and (((@EAP:whiteListed = 'false' or (not(@EAP:whiteListed)))) and ((jcr:contains(@EAP:title, 'with'))) )]
I get 0 results.
This seems to be caused because the word used to do the query, "with", is a reserved keyword. It also happens with "not", "and", "the".
Is there a way to escape or modify the query so I can look for the text "with"? I tried enclosing it with asterisks but it also retrieves nodes containing "without", "withdrawal"...
